# Handling proportion of subplots in Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to create the subplots below using matplotlib.

[image: Subplots]

I have the following code but I cant seem to configure the plots correctly using the arguments.Would appreciate for any help on this. Welcome any other plotting tools on python that could help me stitch 4 plots in this manner too.

Thank you so much!

```
gs1 = fig9.add_gridspec(nrows=8, ncols=8, top=0.6, bottom=0.1,left = 0, right = 0.65,
                        wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
# f9_ax1 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[:1, :1])
ax3 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[:1, 1:])

gs2 = fig9.add_gridspec(nrows=4, ncols=4, top=1.2, bottom=0.4, left = 0, right = 0.5,
                        wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[1: , :1])
ax5 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[1:, 1:])
```

The above code gives this
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can divide the figure for example in a `20 x 20` grid which means that one cell makes up `5% x 5%` of the figure. Scaling your proportions `35/65 -> 7/13`,  `40/60 -> 8/12` and `50/50 -> 10/10` to this grid gives:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=20, ncols=20)
 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0:12, 0:7])     # top left     (size: 12x7  - 60x35)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0:12, 7:20])    # top right    (size: 12x13 - 60x65)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[12:20, 0:10])   # bottom left  (size: 8x10  - 40x50)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[12:20, 10:20])  # bottom right (size: 8x10  - 40x50)
```

[image: grid spec]

Note also the `constrained_layout` keyword, setting this to `True` shrinks the subplots to make all axis labels visible, this has the maybe unwanted affect of changing the aspect ratios slightly. When setting it to `False`
the proportions are better preserved. However currently Constrained Layout is [experimental](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) and maybe changed or removed.

See also the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Create 2 separate gridspecs, where you can set the `height_ratios` to `(6, 4)` for both, but then give them different `width_ratios` as required.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05,
                       height_ratios=(6, 4), width_ratios=(35, 65))
gs2 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05, 
                       height_ratios=(6, 4), width_ratios=(1, 1))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[1, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image]